# bash - sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unterminated `s' command

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, centos, sed

I try to use `sed` command inside a loop to replace IP address, but it is always giving me this error:

`sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unterminated`s' command`

even it is not missing the end slash.

Example format of the IP address: `26.236.16.233`

Here is my code:

```
readarray thearray < /root/scripts/ipaddr.info
Filepath=/var/named/chroot/var/named/$Serverdmn

 for item in ${!thearray[@]}; do
    echo -e "IP: ${thearray[$item]}."
    echo -e "Change this IP? (y/n)"
    read Useranswer
    if [ $Useranswer = y ]; then
        echo -e "Please type the IP address:"
        read Firstipaddress

        oldipaddr=${thearray[$item]}
        new_oldipaddr=${oldipaddr%.*}.0

        newipaddr=$Firstipaddress
        new_ipaddr=${newipaddr%.*}.0            

        # do the change on all files
        sed -i "s/$oldipaddr/$Firstipaddress/g" /root/scripts/ipaddr.info
        sed -i "s/$oldipaddr/$Firstipaddress/g" /etc/application/config
        sed -i "s/$oldipaddr/$Firstipaddress/g" $Filepath
        sed -i "s/$new_oldipaddr/$new_ipaddr/g" $Filepath

    elif [ $Useranswer = n ]; then
                :
    fi
done
```

What will be the problem here and how to solve it?

Comment: I suggest that you print the values of `$oldipaddr`, `$Firstipaddress`, `$new_oldipaddr`, and `$new_ipaddr` before the calls to `sed` to see what you're passing to the application.  Do those variables have any unexpected symbols?

Comment: No unexpected symbols on the value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$oldipaddr` (obtained from `${thearray[$item]}`) values contain newlines read from `/root/scripts/ipaddr.info`, which are causing the `sed` commands to get split across lines, like

```
Please type the IP address:
1.2.3.4
sed -i s/26.236.16.233
/1.2.3.4/g /root/scripts/ipaddr.info
```

Try

```
readarray -t thearray < ipaddr.info
```

From `help mapfile`

```
      -t        Remove a trailing newline from each line read.
```